# JAVA code for the possible number of combinations of a 6-digit code between ranges of two integers

Tags: java, input, user-input

Conditions of the 6-digit code:

- None of the digits are 0
- Each digit of the combination is different
- The 6-digit number is divisible by each one of the digits

Input:

- Two integers, L and H
- L is the limit on the smallest number on the range
- H is the limit on the largest number on the range

Output:

- C, which defines the number of possible combinations where L<=c<=H

I thought I could use arrays as the condition check, then  realized I couldn't use it to find the number of possible combinations. Tried using loops, but couldn't figure it out, all I got for the pseudocode is the input, then a condition if L is less or equal to H. Then I sort of ran to a brick wall.

Here's the code.

''''''''

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner FF = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int l = FF.nextInt();
    int h = FF.nextInt();
    for (int i = l; i <= h; i++) {
        result.add(i);
    }


    for (int i=l; i<=h; i++){
        if (result.get(i) == result.get(i)){
            result.remove(i);
        }
        int temp = result.get(i);
        while (result.get(i)>0){
            int k = result.get(i)%10;
            if (temp % k != 0){
                result.remove(i);
            }
        }
        if (String.valueOf(result.get(i)).contains("0")){
            result.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't the result independent from minimum / maximum numbers allowed always _6!_ (factorial)?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko here's the code
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class safeCrack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner FF = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = FF.nextInt();
        int end = FF.nextInt();
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            result.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

Comment: @user16320675 no it isn't, or I think it isn't. This was a bonus question that was never answered during my class. It was one of the teaching assistants questions. I don't know if he got it from a competitive or similar site as you said, but I got it from that. I'm sorry to make you think that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stream of integers, here 111111 to 1000000 and then filter out everything what doesnot meet your conditions.

```
public class SixDigitCode {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntStream.iterate(111111, i -> i < 1000000, i -> i + 1)
            .filter(containsZero.negate())
            .filter(digitDifferent)
            .filter(divideByDigits)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}

static IntPredicate containsZero = i -> Integer.toString(i).contains("0");
static IntPredicate digitDifferent = i -> Integer.toString(i).chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 6;
static IntPredicate divideByDigits = i -> Integer.toString(i).chars().boxed()
        .filter( x -> i%Character.getNumericValue(x) ==0)
        .count() ==6;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem. 
Let's start with an easy, but inefficient one:

```
boolean isOk(int number){
   String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
   if(numberStr.contains("0"))
       return false;
   for(int i = 0; i < numberStr.length(); i++){
       for(int j = i + 1; j < numberStr.length(); j++){
           if(numberStr.charAt(i) == numberStr.charAt(j))
               return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}

...
int count = 0;
for(int i = L; i <= H; i++){
    if(isOk(i))
        count ++;
}
```

Note: this code is by no means optimal, but I think it is a straight forward easy to understand solution.
However, I cannot test it right now, so it may contain minor issues.